# Не работает Nginx

Tags: php, windows, nginx

Пишет при заходе на localhost

> No input file specified.

Вот конфиг NGINX

```
server {
     listen       80;
      server_name  yii2-basic.local;
      root  F:\web\test\web;

location / {
    try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # Redirect everything that isn't real file to index.php including arguments.
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location ~ /\.(ht|svn) {
    deny all;
}
```

}

---

из комментария:

вот что в логах нашел:

> 2015/12/16 18:42:48 [crit] 19172#18520: *1 GetFileAttributesEx() "F:\web est/" failed (123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect), client: 127.0.0.1, server: yii2-basic.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

Comment: а Вы уверены что у Вас путь правильно прописан???

Comment: Копировал из проводника.

Comment: А скриншот можно что лежит здесь?? F:\web\test\web

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/NkbcRySKmGXrF

Comment: а что за версия nginx

Comment: Точную не знаю. Однако вот что в логах нашел

`2015/12/16 18:42:48 [crit] 19172#18520: *1 GetFileAttributesEx() "F:\web est/" failed (123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect), client: 127.0.0.1, server: yii2-basic.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

Comment: У тебя либо нету этой директории, либо к ней путь прописан не правильно!

Comment: да нет просто \t как знак табуляции сработал попробуй переименовать в что нибудь другое. и из под чего запущен nginx?

Comment: В корень диска надо папку класть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `root  F:\web\test\web;`

путь следует указать в «unix-стиле»:

```
root  F:/web/test/web;
```

иначе происходит интерпретация «escape-последовательностей» и, например, `\t` превращается в символ табуляции, что видно из приведённого лога:

> "F:\web est/" failed (123: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)